# wxWidgets linking error, undefined references and wx-config not found

Tags: eclipse, windows, linker, wxwidgets

So I tried to compile and link a simple example of wxWidgets in Eclipse, but every time I want to use `wx-config --cxxflags` or `wx-config --libs` , Eclipse tells me no such file ro directory. The program compliles fine without those flags, though, but linking gives me an awful lot of undefined reference errors ... I already use wxWidgets on Ubuntu, without any problems but I'm new to using this on windows.

This is the source code:

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
class MyApp: public wxApp {
public:
virtual bool OnInit(){
    return true;
}
};
```

The error:

```
g++ "src\\TestMinimal.o" -mwindows -o TestMinimal.exe 
src\TestMinimal.o: In function `ZN8wxObjectaSERKS_':
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/MinGW/include/wx-3.0/wx/object.h:374: undefined reference to `wxObject::Ref(wxObject const&)'
src\TestMinimal.o: In function `ZN23wxCriticalSectionLockerC1ER17wxCriticalSection':
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/MinGW/include/wx-3.0/wx/thread.h:307: undefined reference to `wxCriticalSection::Enter()'
ect...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use Cygwin, you won't have `wx-config` under Windows, so you need to manually specify both the compilation and linking options as [explained in the documentation](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/docs/msw/install.txt#L458).

Comment: I did that and the errors dissapeared. However, when I tried to run the .exe file, the system complained about dll files missing. So I copied the dll files into the directory and the program is launching without errors, but is not doing anyting (no window is shown, I'm compiling the hello world from wxWidgets btw)

Comment: DLLs need to be in the PATH or in the same directory as the program, this is just how Windows works. As for your program above, it doesn't do anything, so it's not clear what do you expect to happen.